# 6Jquery datepicker date blocking not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written code to block past dates and dates in the unavilabledates array, but only the second element of the array is blocked, rest are available for selection. Any idea how to figure it out?

```
var unavailableDates = ["6-3-2016", "5-28-2016", "5-27-2016", "6-28-2016"];

var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
    onRender:function(date){
        dmy = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" +date.getDate() + "-" +  date.getFullYear();
        return (date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() || ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 1))?'disabled':'';
    }
}
```

Output:`// 5-28-2016` blocked , rest are not

Comment: If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.

Comment: There is a `});` missing at the end of your code… In `var unavailableDates` you have 2 times `"5-28-2016"` in this array.

Comment: even if i have single element i get the same answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you use the jQuery UI Datepicker, use the beforeShowDay function instead of the onRender:

```
var unavailableDates = ["2016-03-06"]; // Dates formatted the same way as the beforeShowDay formatDate() function requires it

$('#dpd1').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ unavailableDates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    },
    minDate: 0
});
```

**EDIT**

I found the error, the formatDate('yy-mm-dd') in the beforeShowDay function checks for a 2016-05-25 date, while your provided array has dates like 6-3-2016. This is way the dates are not disabled.

See the updated code and a jsfiddle to go with it: https://jsfiddle.net/orttL83d/ (In this example I disabled 26th of May and all past dates)

Comment: Bu I need to block past dates also. How can I use this approach to block past dates?

Comment: Just put any date you want into the 'unavailableDates' array and they will be disabled, no matter if they are in the future or in the past.

Comment: thts ineffective, as a whole i need to block all past dates and specific future dates

Comment: From you comment I understood you also had to block 'certain' past dates. Added the 'minDate' option and set it to '0', that way you cannot select past dates full stop, I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I have tested this code, but it doesn't work, i can still select all the days in the unavailable dates

Comment: Thanks @milanzor, it helps